# In ios how to support multiple screen sizes programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

In ios development some scenarios we have to programmatically create the interface or need to generate interface depending on some conditions. I want to know how to support multiple screen sizes programmatically without using auto layout.

Comment: Is your app is for both iPad and iPhone?

Comment: @CharanGiri only iphones

Comment: write this method +(NSString *)yesButWhichDeviceIsIt in app delegate and reuse in other classes. As your app is only for iPhone you need to take care of only height. this will work for iPod also you need not to add any other conditions in this method

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like following

```
 CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    if (screenSize.height > 480.0f)
    {
        //Do iphone5 Stuff here
    }
    else
    {
         //Do iphone classic Stuff here
    }
}
else
{
       //Do ipad Stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use some of the macros

```
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
#define IS_IPHONE_5 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE_4 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480.0f)
#define IS_IOS7 ((floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber)>NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1))
#define IS_LANDSCAPE ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
#define IS_RETINA ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(displayLinkWithTarget:selector:)] && ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.0))
```

Put all the macros above the interface in .h and start using it in your .m files

You can check in any of your viewcontrollers by using this

```
-(void)createControls{
   if(IS_IPHONE){
      //Do iphone stuff
   }
   else{
      //Do ipad stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for replying, please can you also tell that if I have a imageview positioned top center of device now when I rotate the device how to handle this including multi sizes.

Comment: There are lot factor should be considered when developing for both orientations. Either you can handle fully using the xib autolayout mask or constraints. But while considering coding it will be very complex. Hope you search some tutorials on it in google

Answer (score 1):

```
+(NSString *)yesButWhichDeviceIsIt
{
    BOOL hasRetina = NO;
    if ([UIScreen instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
        CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
        if (scale > 1.0) {
            hasRetina = YES;
        }
    }
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        if (hasRetina) {
            return @"iPad retina";
        } else {
            return @"iPad";
        }
    } else {
        if (hasRetina) {
            if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568){
                return @"iPhone5";
            }
            else
            {
                return @"iPhone4s";
            }
        } else {
            return @"iPhone";
        }
    }
}
```

By using above method you will get device type, based on the result you can code:

```
NSString *deviceTypeString=[self yesButWhichDeviceIsIt];
if([deviceTypeString isEqualToString: @"iPhone5"])
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(NSString *)whichiOSDevice
    {
        BOOL hasRetina = NO;
        if ([UIScreen instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
                CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
               if (scale > 1.0) {
                    hasRetina = YES;
                   }
             }
         if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
                if (hasRetina) {
                     return @"iPad retina";
                    } else {
                   return @"iPad";
                   }
                 } else {
         if (hasRetina) {
                        if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568){
                             return @"iPhone5";
                        }
                     else
                         {
                           return @"iPhone4s";
                          }
                    } else {
                  return @"iPhone";
                 }
               }
          }
```